# LinkageError occurred while loading main class com while running the command line sdkmanager --list

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

when I am running the command on the command line after setting the environment variable it is showing the error saying:
LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Can anyone please tell me what to do? I am setting android sdk manually for eclipse.

Comment: Class file version 61 is Java 17, version 55 is Java 11. Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

you're encountering a version incompatibility issue between the Java runtime and the compiled class files of the Android SDK tools. Specifically, it seems that the Android SDK tools you're using have been compiled with a newer version of Java (class file version 61.0), which is not compatible with the version of Java you're using to run the SDK Manager CLI (which supports class file versions up to 55.0).

Try updating the java development kit
and also Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android development, and Android Studio is the recommended IDE